# Trying to connect to a raspberry pi web socket with GDScript

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, godot, gdscript, godot4

I wrote Python code on a Raspberry Pi that sends data when the sound sensor is triggered. when I connect to it using Python script everything works fine but for some reason Godot 4 doesn't recognize buttons pressed through t keyboard.press_and_release() so I thought about making the connection directly in Godot's gdscript. For some reason, the status is always connecting even when the serverside says it is connected.

I'm using WebSocketPeer in GDScript to connect to the URL. if there are any alternatives I would love some advice or maybe just a way to register the responses received by the py script as Godot input

**Solution**

i created a global file that connects to the pi server when the game starts:

```
extends Node

var players = []
var scene
const port = 8880
var ip = "192.168.4.1"
var connection 

func _ready():
    connection = StreamPeerTCP.new()
    connection.connect_to_host( ip,port )
```

then I just use the responses and simulate buttons where I need:

```
func _process(delta):
    GameData.connection.poll()
    
    var state = GameData.connection.get_status()
    
    if GameData.connection and state == GameData.connection.STATUS_CONNECTED:
        if GameData.connection.get_available_bytes() > 0:
            var s = GameData.connection.get_utf8_string(GameData.connection.get_available_bytes())
            print(str(s))
            if str(s) == "1":
                Input.action_press("1")
            elif str(s) == " ":
                Input.action_press("space")
```

Comment: Some questions: What do you mean by "making the connection directly in [...] gdscript"? Is your server expecting WebSocket? Or could it be looking for a TCP or UDP connection? Also what is `keyboard.press_and_release()`?

Comment: Make sure to post relevant example code in the future. For example, providing code context for how you are connecting to the server using WebSocketPeer in GDScript or showing `press_and_release()` since that is not a Godot API and the reader may not be familiar with raspi python libraries.

Comment: thank you for the help, I found a way to connect to the WebSocket, it was just hard as the new Godot documentation doesn't really help with it but was actually much easier than I expected and the solution code in the question for anyone that has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the question as well now just to make it easier to find but ill post it here:

i created a global file that connects to the pi server when the game starts:

```
extends Node

var players = []
var scene
const port = 8880
var ip = "192.168.4.1"
var connection 

func _ready():
    connection = StreamPeerTCP.new()
    connection.connect_to_host( ip,port )
```

then I just use the responses and simulate buttons where I need:

```
func _process(delta):
    GameData.connection.poll()
    
    var state = GameData.connection.get_status()
    
    if GameData.connection and state == GameData.connection.STATUS_CONNECTED:
        if GameData.connection.get_available_bytes() > 0:
            var s = GameData.connection.get_utf8_string(GameData.connection.get_available_bytes())
            print(str(s))
            if str(s) == "1":
                Input.action_press("1")
            elif str(s) == " ":
                Input.action_press("space")
```